# container hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I want to hide a container when we click on remove button inside container and same time in navigation the name of container will be visible.

Now when we click on navigation link of that div, the container will be visible and hide the link from navigation.

I created one to make you more clear :

***[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r66FG/)***

***HTML***

```
<div id="1" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="2" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="3" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="4" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add">Container 1</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add">Container 2</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add">Container 3</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add">Container 4</a>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.main-container {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('.rem-widget').live("click", function() {
    var currentId2 = $(this).parents(".main-container").attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId2).hide('slow');

    var currentId2 = $(this).parents(".nav-widget-add").attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId2).show('slow');
});

$('.nav-widget-add').live("click", function() {
    var currentId2 = $(this).parents(".main-containe").attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId2).show('slow');

    var currentId2 = $(this).parents("").attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId2).hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: you want to hide only the clicked container? if you click on the another container, the hidden container should show?

Comment: check jquery docs for `show()` and `hide()`

Comment: @CJRamki YES, I want to hide only that container is clicked. Each container will hide accordingly and the container which hides its displays the name in navigation.

Comment: @CJRamki No, on each container is different, there will be no effect on any container on another.

Comment: Its working find ,i checked your fiddle What else do you want?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Its not working what i want. please read it carefully..

Comment: @Ranjeet more over i completed... Wait.. i will provide the completed fiddle

Comment: Please explain the Problem properly,Users are not getting what you want to say,So you are getting -3 votes.You may be banned to ask Questions ,ITs very dangerous!

Comment: @CJRamki ok! I am waiting.. :)

Comment: @Ranjeet i posted my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
 <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.main-container a.rem-widget').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().hide('slow');
     $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).show('slow');
});
$('.navigation a').click(function(){
     $(this).hide('slow');
     $('#'+$(this).attr('class')).parent().show('slow');
});

});
</script>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget" id="nav-widget-add1">Remove</a>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget" id="nav-widget-add2">Remove</a>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget" id="nav-widget-add3">Remove</a>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
    <a href="#" class="rem-widget" id="nav-widget-add4">Remove</a>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add1">Container 1</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add2">Container 2</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add3">Container 3</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="nav-widget-add4">Container 4</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes! looking for same but just one thing is left i.e I need to hide and show whole container not only "Remove".

Comment: i just edited my code to hide the container of the clicked link try now

Comment: thanks alot for this it worked absolutely fine and got what i was looking for.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div id="1" class="main-container"> <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>

</div>
<div id="2" class="main-container"> <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>

</div>
<div id="3" class="main-container"> <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>

</div>
<div id="4" class="main-container"> <a href="#" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>

</div>
<div class="navigation">    <a href="#" class="nav-widget-add" data-navi="1">Container 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-widget-add" data-navi="2">Container 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-widget-add" data-navi="3">Container 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-widget-add" data-navi="4">Container 4</a>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.main-container {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
}

.nav-widget-add {
    display:none;
}
```

this **javascript** code will make the container transparent when click on the remove link.

**SEE THIS FIDDLE** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/r66FG/10/)

```
$('.rem-widget').click(function () {
    $(this).hide('slow');
    $(this.parentNode).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $('a[data-navi=' + this.parentNode.id + ']').show('slow');
});

$('.nav-widget-add').click(function () {
    var navIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#' + this.dataset.navi).css('background-color', 'grey').children('.rem-widget').show('slow');
    $(this).hide('slow');
});
```

this **javascript** code will hide the container when click on the remove link.

```
$('.rem-widget').click(function () {
    $(this.parentNode).hide('slow');
    $('a[data-navi=' + this.parentNode.id + ']').show('slow');
});

$('.nav-widget-add').click(function () {
    $('#' + this.dataset.navi).show('slow');
    $(this).hide('slow');
});
```

**SEE THIS FIDDLE** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/r66FG/9/)

Comment: Thanks alot..  It worked fine but I used another one from below. But still thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Your question was quite confusing. But as per your comments, i think this is what you want. I hope I am write.

Change you HTML to this

```
<div id="1" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" id="maincontainer1" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="2" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" id="maincontainer2" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="3" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" id="maincontainer3" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="4" class="main-container">
    <a href="#" id="maincontainer4" class="rem-widget">Remove</a>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#" id="container1" class="nav-widget-add">Container 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="container2"  class="nav-widget-add">Container 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="container3"  class="nav-widget-add">Container 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="container4"  class="nav-widget-add">Container 4</a>
</div>
```

and your jQuery to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container1').hide();
    $('#container2').hide();
    $('#container3').hide();
    $('#container4').hide();
    $('#maincontainer1').click(function() {
                $('#1').hide('slow');
                $('#container1').show();
    });

    $('#maincontainer2').click(function() {
                $('#2').hide('slow');
                $('#container2').show();
    });

    $('#maincontainer3').click(function() {
                $('#3').hide('slow');
                $('#container3').show();
    });

    $('#maincontainer4').click(function() {
                $('#4').hide('slow');
                $('#container4').show();
    });
    $('#container1').click(function() {
                $('#1').show('slow');
                $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#container2').click(function() {
                $('#2').show('slow');
                $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#container3').click(function() {
                $('#3').show('slow');
                $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#container4').click(function() {
                $('#4').show('slow');
                $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakashihatake2/r66FG/3/)

What I did was:

1. Added Id to each anchor tag (Remove link)
2. I have hidden all containers in navigation in the beginning
3. And the rest, you can see :)